# How to split a column from a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split a column from a Data frame. I know this can be easily achieved using str.split(), but when I split it should return 7 columns, but it only return the first column.

This is the column I am trying to split:

```
print(df1['Genres'])

 0                                          ['Drama']
 1                                 ['Crime', 'Drama']
 2                                 ['Crime', 'Drama']
 3           ['Action', 'Crime', 'Drama', 'Thriller']
 4                                 ['Crime', 'Drama']
                           ...
```

And this is my code so far:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('Dataset01.csv'))

df1['Genres'] = df1['Genres'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip("["))
df1['Genres'] = df1['Genres'].map(lambda x: x.rstrip("]"))
df1['Genres'] = df1['Genres'].str.replace("'", '')

df1['Genres'] = df1['Genres'].str.split(",", expand=True)

df1
```

I only get the column with the first values:

```
print(df1['Genres'])

0          Drama
1          Crime
2          Crime
3         Action
4          Crime
         ...
```

This is how the DataFrame looks like after I run the code:
[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6xGg.png)

As you can see it only returns one column

Is there something else I can do to split the columns? Or is there something I can do to fix that?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of the data as dictionary or dataframe constructor? `['Crime', 'Drama']` is ambiguous, we can't know if this is a string or a list of strings

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) then [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html)

```
import ast 
df1['Genres'].map(ast.literal_eval).explode()
```